# What is the recommended way to have an inline array member of dynamic size?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I want a class with an inline array (Not a pointer to another array) member, that can be of different size that is specified during the creation of the class. Something like:

```
template<typename T>
class Buffer {

...
...
private:
  T events_[size]; // This size should be determined during compilation time.
}
```

I could use something like this:

```
template<typename T, int size>
class Buffer {

...
...
private:
  T events_[size]; // This size is determined during compilation time.
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes there is, [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: As a general tip, if ever you have the phrases "dynamic size" and "array" in the same sentence, then in over 99% of the cases you want `std::vector`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I think the problem description is pretty clear that a vector (or similar) is not the answer the OP is looking for. Because of this I think there is no answer to this question.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg std::vector does not inline an array. It is a pointer to an array. I don't want the pointer indirection. Also I don't need the array to be re-sized once created.

Comment: Your comment in-code on the second snippet is not accurate. that size is determined at compilation time. if you can use that, then do so. *Dynamic* creation size is *computed* at runtime, and for that something like `std::vector<>` is preferred (especially to to hand-rolling your own solution). If you want it as a data blob *and* part of the structure, I'm afraid you're SOL, since ttbomy flexible arrays (the only thing I can think of that would fit remotely to your requirements) are not part of the C++ standard.

Comment: The difference between an array declared as an array, and an array from a pointer is... almost nothing. They are almost completely interchangeable (you can't assign to a variable declared as an array, that's about it), and in fact arrays decays to pointers as soon as you pass it around.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg that isn't true. `struct IntArr { int ar[10]; };` and `struct IntArr { int *arr; }` are nowhere *close* to equivalent. The OP wants the former, not a solution that involves the latter or derivatives therein (like a `std::vector<>`, which is just a managed pointer anyway).

Comment: @WhozCraig Sorry I have edited the question to show that the size is known at compile time.

Comment: If compile-time is ok, then what you have should be more than adequate. So is that the question? You can't get much simpler than that. But note, they *are* different types depending on the template parameter. I.e. `Buffer<int,10>` and `Buffer<int,5>` are *not* the same type. Pointers to said same, equivalence checks, etc, are not going to likely work as you intend without some legwork.

Comment: What I meant was that the compiler most likely won't generate different code for indexing an array compared to indexing a pointer. If you have an array `a` and a pointer `p`, doing e.g. `a[1]` and `p[1]` will most likely result in the same "pointer indirection".

Comment: @JoachimPileborg the moment that pointer member is loaded in any sort of register, that is certainly logical to assume, and I concur the math is ultimately the same.

Comment: If you have the size at compile-time, why not create the array at compile time? Either use a normal array, or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). Either of your example would work fine.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg They are not the same in terms of the memory layout. This matters to me because I need exact control on the memory layout. You are right that if I have the size at compile time I could just use a normal array.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg "[almost no] difference between an array declared as an array, and an array from a pointer / ...almost completely interchangeable (you can't assign to a variable declared as an array, that's about it)" - consider `template <size_t N> void f(T (&a)[N] { }` and how useful it is in detecting passed-in array dimensions, enforcing or specialising same-size array operations etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a perfectly acceptable way to do what you want. If you know the size you want at compile-time a template parameter is a good approach. It is standards compliant and doesn't involve any trickery. What more could you want?

Look at `std:array` to see this approach being used in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<typename T>
class Buffer {

    Buffer(std::size_t size) : events_(new T[size]) {}
    ~Buffer() { delete[] events_; }

private:
    T* events_;
}
```

is the closest you're going to be able to get without using compiler-specific extensions allowing C99 VLAs in C++. In standard C++, array sizes are fixed at compile-time, and that's that -- if you want the size decided at run-time, you have to use heap allocation.

Of course, using `std::vector<T>` to wrap the heap allocation in a nice API is a much better idea than rolling your own :-)

Comment: This doesn't address what the OP wants. He wants an allocation that includes the content as *part* of the Buffer structure, not a pointer to it buried within.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't too clear with the question. I want `struct IntArr { int ar[10]; }; and not struct IntArr { int *arr; }`

Answer (score 0):

Seems your requirements are to have a 'flat' object of dynamic size.

I would do something like this

```
template <class T>
class Buffer
{
public:
    Buffer(size_t size) : size_(size) {}
    ...
private:
    size_t size_;
    const T* events() const { return reinterpret_cast<const T*>(this + 1); }
    T* events() { return reinterpret_cast<T*>(this + 1); }
};

Buffer<int>* buf = new char[sizeof(Buffer<int>) + n*sizeof(int)];
new (buf) Buffer<int>(n);
```

The `events` methods can be used to access the events, which exist just past the end of the `Buffer` object.

It's ugly because of the two step object creation process and the fact that `Buffer` must be dynamically allocated. But I think it's the best that can be done to meet your requirements. Also if `T` is a non-POD type then you need to make sure those are initialised too.

Comment: It's not standard compliant. Your reinterpret_cast from `Buffer<T>*` to `T*` is undefined.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y Yes, it's a compromise.

Comment: However, a `static_cast<void*>` followed by a `static_cast<T*>` should work -- get outermost `this` pointer, which must be `b`, and then cast it to `T*`.  However, there is this annoying issue of alignment...

Comment: @john I revised my question to only require compile time knowledge of the size.

Comment: @Rajiv Hmm, that's disappointing, seems I wasted my time. Since you know the size at compile time what's wrong with the method you already have?

Comment: @john, I apologize, it was a DOH moment. I did learn something new from your answer though.